# How to upgrade JWPlayer from version 5.10 to 7

Tags: javascript, web, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

We are using `JWPlayer 5.10` which is old now. So we want to upgrade it to `version 7` which is the latest version. I did some research on how to upgrade this but didn't find anything. I have read `jwplayer 7` documentation and it's not an easy task for me. Any suggestions is appreciated! It will be great if there is an automated way to upgrade it.

Comment: Check the answer and let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to upgrade it, it depends on which edition you are using free/premium/enterprise edition.

1)
**Free edition :** You can simply go to jwplayer site and sign up and get the player

1. Sign up in http://www.jwplayer.com/sign-up/
2. Log-In https://account.jwplayer.com/ . it will redirect you to https://dashboard.jwplayer.com/
3. Click on *License Keys & Downloads*
   [image]
4. Download the player or use cloud player library url

[image]

So **JWPLAYER VERSION 7** is available for free user

[image]

2) If you have **Premium/Enterprise version of jwplayer**, contact the [support team](http://www.jwplayer.com/contact-us/) and they will send you the Jwplayer latest version.

Helpful Link : http://www.jwplayer.com/pricing/

Comment: I thought JW7 was available to licensed users only. Did they release a free version? I wouldn't be surprised since they made their mobile SDKs available for free.

Comment: @zer00ne :  Yes, it is available for free version, follow the steps which i have told in answer. If answer is correct, kindly accept it as correct answer and upvote it :) Happy to help you

Comment: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403726-what-s-new-in-jw-player-7-x-

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I'll upvote for that info on that policy change. Btw I was confusing things with the mobile SDKs being free, I was thinking about Swift being open source, sorry.

Comment: I would imagine the question from the OP is more concerned with how to upgrade their embed code from JW5 to JW7 - maybe they can clarify.

All you've provided are the details of how to get a JW7 key - which isn't really answering the question of upgrading...

Comment: @jherrieven - If there is a way to upgrade their embed code from JW5 to JW7, please add it as answer. I am also curious to know how to do it. Thanks